# GEB/Selenium: Connect to localhost failed: Connection refused

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, automation, geb

I'm trying to pick-up geb-spock using the Firefox/Gecko Driver but every time I'm building and attempting to run the test, I get an error that the connection on localhost can not be opened.
Do you have any idea related to this?

> Nov 19, 2016 2:50:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>   Caught: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:32426 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'NOT SHOWN', ip: 'Ask for it', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:32426 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'NOT SHOWN', ip: 'Ask for it', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
>       at geb.driver.NameBasedDriverFactory.getDriver(NameBasedDriverFactory.groovy:42)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$_getDriver_closure3.doCall(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:80)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$_getDriver_closure3.doCall(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:30)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:79)
>       at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:306)
>       at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:295)
>       at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:101)
>       at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:367)
>       at geb.Browser$go$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>       at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:359)
>       at Test1$_run_closure1.doCall(Test1.groovy:11)
>       at Test1$_run_closure1.doCall(Test1.groovy)
>       at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:701)
>       at geb.Browser$drive$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
>       at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:671)
>       at geb.Browser$drive.call(Unknown Source)
>       at Test1.run(Test1.groovy:9)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:32426 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       ... 27 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>       ... 42 more

Comment: Got a failing example?

Comment: I was just trying to start the browser and go to google:

`import geb.Browser
/**
 * Created by anon on 00/0/0000.
 */


System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe")

Browser.drive {

    go "http://google.ro"

    assert title == "Google"

    $("input", title = "Search").click()
}`